# Passing subsequence of a stream without copying its content into a new instance

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

Let's assume I have following method:

```
void Upload(Stream stream)
{
    // uploads the content of the specified stream somewhere
}
```

And let's further assume I got some binary file `f`, which contains some data I'd like to upload with the method above. 
**But**: It's not the whole file I want to upload. It's only a certain part of `f`. More precisely the desired data starts at a certain position `s >= 0` and ends at a certain position `e <= f.Length`.

Is there a way to pass a `Stream` instance, which starts at position `s`, with the length of `e`, without copying all bytes between `s` and `e` into a new stream instance? I'm asking because there is the possibility, that file `f` is quite big and I don't want to make assumptions on potentially available RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider using [Stream.CanSeek Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [Stream.Position Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [Stream.Seek Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to "access" the certain part of the stream.

To have a separate `Stream` instance with appropriate length, it seems it is required to implement a `SubStream` class — the wrapper which represents sub-stream. The following references can be useful to implement such a wrapper:

1. [How to access part of a FileStream or MemoryStream, Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c409b63b-37df-40ca-9322-458ffe06ea48/how-to-access-part-of-a-filestream-or-memorystream?forum=netfxbcl).
2. [How to expose a sub section of my stream to a user, Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949441/490018).

Comment: I'm afraid, that's not possible here. I'm handling some mixed serialized data and need to upload a part of it using the AWS SDK, which either accepts a path to a file or a `Stream`. Even if I set the `Position` property accordingly, I could not limit the stream length, without trunctating the actual stream (I guess..).

Comment: @wodzu, thank you for pointing out. The answer has been updated.

Comment: That's definitely a good idea implementing a `SubStream` class. I'll review this and Xavier's suggestion tomorrow and tell you guys, what I decided to do.

Comment: I ended up using Marc Gravell's solution from the first link. It's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I think that was the only reasonable approach for my issue. I extended Marc's solution, so I could read from several streams as if it would be just a single one. Thanks again.

Comment: @wodzu, you are welcome! It seems the extended solution could be posted as an answer to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6949441/490018).

Answer (score 1):

If modifying the pointers in the original stream before calling the method will work, then use [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx) to set the starting position and [SetLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.setlength.aspx) to set the end position. Then, you can pass the stream to the method and it should only touch that section (assuming it does not internally seek back to the beginning).

Unfortunately, `SetLength` will truncate the stream, so you won't be able to later access the rest of it if you needed to for some reason. However, if that is not a requirement, this should work.

Edit: Since you need to preserve the original stream, these are the other options I can think of:

- If you have access to the path (and it is not locked by the other stream), you could open a new stream to the file and send a truncated version of that stream.
- You could copy the section you need to a new stream, such as a `MemoryStream`. You won't need to copy the entire file, but you would need to copy the part you are going to upload using [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx) and [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx).

  ```
  byte[] data = new byte[size];
  stream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  stream.Read(data, 0, size);
  using (MemoryStream subStream = new MemoryStream(data))
  {
      Upload(subStream);
  }
  ```
- You could write your own stream implementation that does what you want, accessing only a specific part of another stream.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm accessing a singletone instance of that stream, which must not be trunctaded, because succeeding calls will most probably want access some other part outside the trunctated range.

Comment: Updated with alternate suggestions.

Comment: When I saw you mentioning `MemoryStream` I intuitively rejected your idea, but when I thought about uploading big files I came to the conclusion, that it would be better to splitt the file into chunks before uploading. I certainly want to avoid situations, when I would have to reinitialize the upload of the full file in case of a connection issue. Fortunately the AWS SDK (which I'm using) offers to upload files in several parts. This was definitely a useful post of yours. I update the question tomorow as it's a little late in central europe right now.