# How can I deserialize a JSON array without "," separator?

Tags: .net-core, json.net

I have a JSON file, I have to deserialize it, but there isn't comma separator between objects, how can I add it or deserialize it while ignoring the fact that the separator is missing?

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "items":[
        {"itemId": "1", "name": "name1"},
        {"itemId": "2", "name": "name2"},
        {"itemId": "3", "name": "name3"}
    ]
}
{
    "id": "124",
    "items":[
        {"itemId": "4", "name": "name4"},
        {"itemId": "5", "name": "name5"},
        {"itemId": "6", "name": "name6"}
    ]
}]
```

I know I can correct the JSON file by adding the separator manually, but my JSON is very big, to do it is not a good idea, this is why I try to find a work around.

Comment: The structure you're showing is not valid JSON.  (It has two top-level objects, which would otherwise be in a top-level array to make it valid.)  To use a JSON deserializer, you need to start with valid JSON.  Otherwise what you have is a custom data format and you'd write custom logic to parse it.

Comment: thank you David, but this is my condition

Comment: What exactly are you asking then?  How to parse custom data?  You'd do that with custom logic.  *Segments* of the data shown are valid JSON, so you can write custom logic to divide this into segments and parse those as JSON individually.  Though it would be *much* easier to correct the *source* of this data instead.  Whoever is providing you with this is not providing valid JSON.  Get them to fix it.

Comment: I have a normal json file, my own problem is that the comma (,) is missing between objects. Between id: 123 and id:124

Comment: *"I have a normal json file"* - Then what are you showing in the question?  Because that is not valid JSON.  If you can correct it to be valid JSON then you can use a JSON deserializer to parse it.  It's really not clear what you're trying to ask here.  You can use JSON parsing tools to parse valid JSON data, not to parse custom data which isn't valid JSON.  What isn't clear about that?

Comment: I can correct it adding the separator manually, but my json is very big, to do it is not a good idea, this is why I try to find a work around.

Comment: Your options are: (1) Correct the source of the data to produce valid JSON; or (2) Write your own parsing logic to parse your custom non-JSON data (which may include using standard JSON parsing for valid subsets of that data).  I recommend the former approach if possible.

Comment: Right.  It would be better to write a short script to fix the JSON errors (which is not hard) and then let the normal JSON tools go to work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the content of your file is malformed JSON.  You cannot parse that out-of-the-box with Json.NET (or System.Text.Json). For confirmation you may upload your file to https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, either one will report errors. Ideally you should get whomever generated the file to fix their serializer.

That being said, if for business reasons you **must** parse this vaguely JSON-ish content, and in addition your file is huge enough that you need to stream through it rather than e.g. loading it into a `string` and fixing it with a regex, you can do so as follows.  You may consider that your file consists of the following sections:

1. A leading junk character `[`.  You can simply skip past this using a `TextReader`.
2. A sequence [newline-delimited JSON](https://ndjson.org/) objects.  You can parse these by setting [`JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm).
3. A trailing junk character `]`.  You can ignore this by catching and swallowing the `JsonReaderException` that Json.NET throws when encountering it.

A file consisting of such sections can be parsed using Json.NET as follows:

```
// Get a stream and TextReader for your JSON.
using var stream = File.OpenRead(jsonFileName);
using var textReader = new StreamReader(stream);

// Skip the leading junk character [
textReader.SkipPast('[');
int nItems = 0;
try
{
    // Deserialize each JSON object.
    foreach (var item in JsonExtensions.DeserializeMultipleContent<Root>(textReader))
    {
        // Do something with each item.
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
        nItems++;
    }
}
catch (JsonReaderException ex)
{
    // Ignore the exception from the trailing character ]
    Console.WriteLine("Processed {0} items until {1}: \"{2}\"", nItems, ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
}
```

Using the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TItem> DeserializeMultipleContent<TItem>(TextReader reader, JsonSerializerSettings settings = default)
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { SupportMultipleContent = true })
        {
            while (jsonReader.Read())
                yield return serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}

public static class TextReaderExtensions
{
    public static TTextReader SkipPast<TTextReader>(this TTextReader reader, char ch) where TTextReader : TextReader
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var c = reader.Read();
            if (c == -1 || c == ch)
                return reader;
        }
    }
}
```

And data model:

```
public record Item(string itemId, string name);
public record Root(string id, List<Item> items);
```

Notes:

- If you don't like the idea of catching and swallowing the `JsonReaderException`, and your JSON stream is seekable, as an alternative you could mask the leading and trailing brackets from Json.NET by using one of the `SubStream` implementations from *[How to expose a sub section of my stream to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949441)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UkLQ3T).